# Numba tuple slicing issue - Excepted an integer

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, numba

Can anyone help me understand why the following code using Numba gives me an error? I can't see anything in the documentation that explains why this would not work: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/index.html

```
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit

@autojit
def foo(arr):
    # works fine
    return arr[:3]

@autojit
def bar(arr):
    # does not work
    return arr.shape[:2]

print foo(np.arange(10))
print bar(np.zeros((1,2,3)))
```

The error given is

```
numba.error.NumbaError: (see below)
--------------------- Numba Encountered Errors or Warnings ---------------------
    return arr.shape[:2]
----------------------^
Error 10:22: Excepted an integer
```

The version  is:

```
>>> numba.__version__
'0.10.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list slicing method is not yet implemented in numba.
I looked up quite a lot of documentation on autojit in numba, and finally I found this -
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/pythonstuff.html#typed-containers
(Check the end part where they mention that slicing is not yet implemented)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Will keep an eye on it in case it changes in future versions.